# windows not defined when Node.js trying to read export default variable from react file (node.js reads react file)

Tags: node.js, reactjs, sitemap

When I am trying to read the react file that contains the router node crash with error ( i want to build sitemap but even if i just try to console.log the export default variable i am getting this error maybe babel wrong configuration?):

> redux\store.js:80 var store = (0, _redux.createStore)(_index2.default,
>   defaultState, (0, _redux.compose)((0,
>   _redux.applyMiddleware)(_reduxThunk2.default), window.devToolsExtension ? window.devToolsExtension() : function (f) {
>                                                                                                                                             ^
>
> ReferenceError: window is not defined

Is it possible to fix that error?

```
react file test.js

require('es6-promise').polyfill();

import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import store, { history } from './redux/store';
import { Router, Route, IndexRoute } from 'react-router';
import App from './app';
....

const renderRouter = (<Provider store={store}>
      <Router history={history} >
        <Route path="/" component={App}>
.....
</Router>
</Prodiver
)

export default renderRouter;
```

sitemap file

```
require('babel-register');

const renderRouter = require('./test').default;
console.log(renderRouter);

/*
const Sitemap = require('react-router-sitemap').default;

(
    new Sitemap(router)
        .build('https://www.omgomg.com')
        .save('./sitemap.xml')
);*/
```

**EDIT:**
If i remove import store and history and I get @import error from App component ( it has scss file so I believe babel isn't config to read scss? )

```
react file test.js

require('es6-promise').polyfill();

import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
/*import store, { history } from './redux/store';*/
import { Router, Route, IndexRoute } from 'react-router';
const App = 0;
....

const renderRouter = (<Provider >
      <Router >
        <Route path="/" component={App}>
.....
</Router>
</Prodiver
)

export default renderRouter;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you use react-router 4.x ?
If so, there is a issue in Github:
https://github.com/kuflash/react-router-sitemap/issues/71

Comment: I use react-router but my problem is reading the react file. even if i dont try to use react-router-sitemap .on the above example I just try to console log the variable i export from test.js . if i remove redux import it works

Comment: Try to create a .babelrc file and ignore it:

{
  "stage": 0,
  "ignore": [
    "*.scss"
  ]
}